# How to SUM multiple columns using Array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I have been trying to sum the multiple columns and unable to expand the its result to the below rows.

Here is my formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(SUM(K2:K,R2:R)=0,"",SUM(K2:K,R2:R)))
```

but its not working i hope someone can help with this issue.

[Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BDEtciQ9UkUq5Fth5Pz44upHSzCHXBxaPdr1c_IhUYs/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=byrow(K2:R,lambda(z,if(counta(z)=0,,sum(z))))
```

***UPDATED FORMULA***:

```
=byrow(D2:F,lambda(z,if(counta(z)=0,,if(sum(z)=0,,sum(z)))))
```

Comment: thank you but its not making the blank to the 0 values

Comment: u mean like if lets say K3:R3 is totally blank then o/p should be shown as zero?!

Comment: No. If the Row is blank then result should be blank too

Comment: care to share a sample sheet with demo data maybe and desired output(manually entered) so that it gives a clear picture on how to best amend the current formula...

Comment: Alright i can share the sheet but its working fine when i copy and paste the values. But those rows have formulas then its not consider it the blank row. thats the the problem i think.

Comment: attached a  sheet for your reference